# Can you move the padding box away from the left side but not in the middle

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a school project to make a website. What I want to do is make a padding that is slightly away from the left side of the page (provided in a picture below). [image]

this is my source code:

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 129.19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* Links inside the navbar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;

  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 126.4px;
  background-color: inherit;

}

.box {
  width: 720px;
  padding: 10px;
  border : 5px solid #000000;
  margin: 10;


}
/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 126.4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  insert logo                             Insert Title
</head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Aboutus.js"></script>
  <link href="AboutUs.CSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="ISTwebsite.html">Home</a>

    <a href="#contact" class="active">About Us</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Stories
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#contact" >Contact Us</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <body style="background-color:#faecca">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;color:#cf3321";><font-face="Helvetica">Welcome to 'title'</h1>
    <h3 style="text-align: center;color:#cf3321">A Website By Name & Name (cleared because this is stack overflow)</h3></font>
    <br>
    <h2 style = "color:#cf3321;text-align: justify">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; About Us</h3>
    <div class="box"><div style="color:#cf3321;">About us info goes here.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have cleared me and my friends names because this is stack overflow.

I want the padding to line with the words "about us".
could somebody help me?

Comment: you are looking for margin?

Comment: @TemaniAfif if I try margin, the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="padding-left:40px">
    <h2 style = "color:#cf3321;text-align: justify">About Us</h2>
    <div class="box">
        <div style="color:#cf3321;">About us info goes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```